# wget wont work on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

i just get my new web server (Ubuntu 10.04) at Leaseweb and when i try to install Virtualmin i get this error :

> wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
>   --2012-02-11 13:53:03--  http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh Resolving
>   software.virtualmin.com... failed: Temporary failure in name
>   resolution. wget: unable to resolve host address
>   `software.virtualmin.com'

I already do apt-get install build-essential and when i try to re-install wget i have :

> apt-get install wget Reading package lists... Done Building dependency
>   tree        Reading state information... Done wget is already the
>   newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
>   upgraded.

Ping and host also dont working

> host google.com ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that you have DNS-related problem. You need to check the config file `/etc/resolv.conf`. It should contains entries like:

```
nameserver your.dns1.server.ip
nameserver your.dns2.server.ip
```

By the way, re-installing `wget` has nothing to do with the problem. Also, using `host` command confirms this problem.

Comment: I have already some IPS from leaseweb so i comment them and put google dns 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 no it work fine. Thanks a lot.